# Obtaining information of tables being used in stored procedure using DbConnection.GetSchema

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, database-connection, database-schema

Is there a way to obtain information about the tables being used inside stored procedure using `DBConnection.GetSchema()`?

I tried using `DbConnection.GetSchema("Procedures",new string[] {db,null, tableName,null})` and also `DbConnection.GetSchema("ProcedureParameters",new string[]{db,null, procedureName,null})` but in vain :(

For Ex: If the stored Procedure named "SearchEmployeeProcedure" uses Employee table to search the records. Then my output should return only "Employee" table.

Is there a way to obtain the list of tables getting affected by given stored procedure?

PS: Is there a way to obtain independent of dataprovider?

Any help on the same would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is been answered in Microsoft forum. Please find the link below as this might help others who are looking for the same.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f12d5dc-a03a-4057-9162-2e9dbd796d66/obtaining-information-of-tables-being-used-in-stored-procedure-using-dbconnectiongetschema